# Android Emulator Mac Landscape

Tags: android, android-emulator, landscape-portrait

How to test the landscape mode on Android Emulator (Mac) ?

When I press ctrl+fn+11 the emulator turns into landscape mode, but the activity screen remains in portrait orientation. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Does your activity have android:configChanges="orientation" in its manifest entry? That would explain the behavior, since you are then responsible for [overriding onConfigurationChanged() and redrawing your views yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

If you don't need to handle it explicitly, just remove the configChanges attribute and your activity will be destroyed and recreated (you might need to save and restore custom state in this case).

Comment: No, it doesn't have.

It seems strange, becuse everything works fine on my android phone. But it doesn't work on emulator, so I can't test the application for different screens.